# How to Resume Previous running application from An Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-context, resume

Give me a little guidance: 
as My Application is running with Broadcast Receiver and when ever my application in Background and any incoming event comes it triggers the my Application.

Now we want as We are **listening** or playing some video file or browsing on Android Phone 
and with incoming event occur and my application launch(already running in Background),
If i **will ignore the event** , **we want to go back previous running task** (Like browsing, playing 
video file application), How we can achieve?

---

Now I am using The store the running application package and Activity info before triggering the Event , and after finishing using this info we resuming the Activity and
It working fine but Only with Gallery Application Playing of Vedio file is not fine , It Crashes the Application and relaunch the Gallery App.

Please give me some Valuable points to make it up?

---

On calling finish, Previous application resume(Playing of Media file) but when next time
on getting broadcast intent and try to launch the Activity , The Activity is not launching 
and application itself crashing.

---

Answer (score 1):

After a long back I got solution of my problem and we need only use to this api

**moveTaskToBack(true);**

and automatically resumes the previous running task(like browser, media application or any thing)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to start you activity by

```
startActivityForResult(Intent intent)
```

When you call **finish()** in the Activity you should return the the previous one, I am not sure if this will function over between Activity running in different applications. Give it a try :D

Comment: I need to wirte programatically with my job done I will go back to my previous Application, lie resumung the Radio or mrdia player,Browsing. If we going to use this finish how To get previous running application class information to prepare the intent, yhis intent could be anything as I want to what ever previous application runiing that trigger.

Comment: On calling finish, Previous application resume(Playing of Media file) but when next time
on getting broadcast intent and try to launch the Activity , The Activity is not launching 
and application itself crashing.